# Is fflush() necessary after fwrite?

Tags: php

After I use `fwrite`, it is important that the contents of the file are updated immediately, so that other processes that read the same file do not get old information.

When I test, it does not seem to be a problem without `fflush`, the file is immediately updated after `fwrite`.

But I wonder if there is a scenario where the file is not updated immediately and `fflush` is necessary?

Comment: If `fflush()` is the last call of your php script and/or the script only has a couple of users I would say it's negligible. But I would still call it - why not? The function description matches exactly what you want. You should consider using a database of some sort, which is less of a bottleneck for concurrent reads/writes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you give an example of when fflush is significant / important?

Comment: Well if another process must access the written file as quickly as possible you should call `fflush` is soon as you are done using the file. Closing it as well. The use-case of fflush is exactly what you have. That's a pretty good reason. But that is looking into the milliseconds. If you have a couple concurrent users it's not a big problem. But it is correct to use either way.